# Is $R_K$ first countable?

Tags: general-topology

> ### countability of $R_K$

Is **$R_K$**

1. First countable?
2. Second countable?

$R_K$ is $\Bbb R$ with the [$K$-topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-topology).

Comment: $\mathbf{Rk} = \Bbb{R}^k$?

Comment: R with k topology

Comment: till now all i know is RK is 2nd countable for the sets (a, b) and (a, b) − K where the intervals have rational end-points, constitute a countable basis

Comment: plz someone help me with this i gotta an end sem paper on this tomorrow :(

Comment: $K$-topology is interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if $R_K$ is second countable, then it’s automatically first countable. Thus, if you can find a countable base for its topology, you can answer the entire question.

HINT: Start with a familiar countable base $\mathscr{B}$ for the usual topology and modify it by adding only countably many sets to get a countable base for the $K$-topology.

Comment: so, B={collection of all open intervals (a,b) where a and b are rationals will do?}

Comment: @junegirl: That’ll do fine as a countable base for the usual topology; now what sets do you have to add to it to make it a base for the $K$-topology?

Comment: plz help me with this i gotta an end sem paper on this tomorrow :(

Comment: @junegirl: The base given in the Wikipedia article to which I linked your question isn’t countable, but it should give you exactly the idea that you need to modify $\mathscr{B}$ to get a countable base for the $K$-topology.

Comment: all open intervals(a,b) where a and b are rational and all sets of the form (a,b)-K, where K={1/n|n belong to Z_+} ?

Comment: @junegirl: That’s right. Now just check that if $x\in R_K$ and $U$ is an open nbhd of $x$ in the $K$-topology, then there is a $B\in\mathscr{B}$ such that either $x\in B\subseteq U$, or $x\in B\setminus K\subseteq U$, and you’re done.

Comment: but i don't know how do i guarantee the existence of such a B?

Comment: @junegirl: I’ll give you one very big hint. If $x\ne 0$, you can actually find a $B\in\mathscr{B}$ with $x\in B\subseteq U$; you’ll need to use a set of the form $B\setminus K$ only when $x=0$. The topology of $R_K$ differs from that of $\Bbb R$ **only** at $0$. Draw some pictures, considering the three cases $x=0$, $x\in K$, and all other $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: great! but i failed to figure anything out :(

Comment: @junegirl: I’m afraid that I don’t see what more I can say without literally doing the problem in its entirety, and I really don’t want to go quite that far.